# How to load selected language when page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a multilanguage application using React, i18next and i18next-localstorage-cache.
it should be the same language that you select after you refresh the page.
I tried hard but ....
But it is default language.
I want to know how to invalidate the local storage cache of my user when releasing a new version of my translations. How can I do that?

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { reactI18nextModule } from "react-i18next";
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import Cache from 'i18next-localstorage-cache';

import translationEN from '../src/locales/en/translation.json';
import translationRU from '../src/locales/ru/translation.json';
import translationUK from '../src/locales/uk/translation.json';

// const languagedetector = new languagedetector(null, options);
// languagedetector.addDetector(myDectector)


const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: translationEN
  },
  ru: {
    translation: translationRU
  },
  uk: {
    translation: translationUK
  }
}

i18n
  .use(detector)
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  .use(Cache)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },
    Cache: {
      enabled: false,
      prefix: 'translation_',
      expirationTime: Infinity,
      Version: {},
      // defaultVersion: '',
    },
    // detector: {
    //   order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'localstorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag', 'path', ' subdomain'],
    //   lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
    //   lookupCookie: 'i18next',
    //   lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    //   lookupFromPthIndex: 0,
    //   lookupFromSubdomainIndex: 0,

    //   cache: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],
    //   excludeCacheFor: ['cimode'],


    //   cookieMinutes: 10,
    //   cookieDomain: 'myDOmain',

    //   htmlTag: document.documentElement,

    //   checkWhitelist: true
    // }
  });

export default i18n
```

Comment: The local storage provides a client side solution for storing key value pairs. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage For storing the selected language: `window.localStorage.setItem('language', 'en');` For retrieving a language: `window.localStorage.getItem('language');`

Comment: I see that you mention `version` in your code but not using it. Seems like it's what you need. https://github.com/i18next/i18next-localStorage-cache#cache-options

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
lng: "en"
```

inside init() and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On page refresh, for keeping the selected language, you need to store the language value in a storage.(Local storage). After setting the value in localstroage, you simply have to edit the lng key in the configuration to like this.

```
  lng: window.localStorage.getItem('Localelanguage'),
```

Comment: The correct way is: `lng: \`${window.localStorage.getItem("lang")}\``